# Enumerable sets are well ordered?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an enumerable and infinite set. Can we always find an infinite subset $B \subseteq A$ and bijection $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$ such that $\varphi(n+1) \geq \varphi(n), \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I know that any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ can be "well ordered", but i was wondering on infinite enumerable sets. Thanks.

**EDIT:**  And a bijection such that bijection $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$ such that $\varphi(n+1) \geq \varphi(n)$, **or** $\varphi(n) \geq \varphi(n+1)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: What you have written is false as an counterexample take Z

Comment: Sure! Actually, I was thinking on another question, let me edit it!

Comment: No, take $A$ as the negative integers.

Comment: Yeah Sure! Hahaha, i edited again. Thank you, with your answer i'm actually finding what i really wanna ask. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = -\Bbb N$ has no infinite increasing subsequences...

And to the amended question, yes: every infinite subset of an ordered space has an increasing or decreasing subsequence. This is classical (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) e.g.).

Comment: Thank you! Actually your answ er made my reavaliate (again) my question. I edit it, and now I want to know if there is a subset with increasing OR decreasing subsequences.